# Where do I save widget code for wordpress?

Tags: widgets, filesystem

Pretty simple, I've written a widget and I can't find out for the life of me where to save it?! Using the most recent version of wordpress.

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make it a plugin and put it in the plugins folder, or you can make it part of a theme and put it in the theme's functions.php file.